# Sequence converging to one.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that x_0 is a real number and x_n = [1+x_(n-1)]/2 for all natural n. Use the Monotone Convergence Theorem to prove x_n → 1 as n grows.

Can someone please help me? I don't know what to assume since I don't know if it is increasing or decreasing when x_0 < 1 and when x_0 > 1.
Any hint/help would really help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By assumption, $$x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{1+x_n}{2}-x_n=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x_n}{2}.$$ Furthermore, it can be shown by induction that if $x_0<1$, then all elements in the sequence are smaller than $1$, and the equivalent if $x_0=1$ or $x_0>1$.

It follows that there are three possible cases: If $x_0<1$, the sequence is increasing, $x_0>1$ implies the sequence is decreasing, while $x_0=1$ implies the sequence is constant.

Answer (score 0):

You can rearrange $x_n=\dfrac{1+x_{n-1}}{2}$ to $x_n-x_{n-1}= \dfrac{1-x_{n-1}}{2}$ which will tell you whether it is increasing or decreasing when $x_n\lt 1$ or $x_n\gt 1$.

You can also rearrange it to $x_n-1=\dfrac{x_{n-1}-1}{2}$  which tells you that $1$ is a bound.

So now apply the Monotone Convergence Theorem